# How can I minimize the amount of calls to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have lots of images into mysql database, which are painted so: `<img src="/PrintImage.php?$id&width&height&quality" />`.

The problem is that for each image, I am doing a call to the database through a class. To explain it better, here is the code:

**edited: posted entirely class code**

HTML View (example):

```
<img src="/PrintImage.php?id=10&width=120&height=120&quality=100" />
<img src="/PrintImage.php?id=20&width=120&height=120&quality=100" />
```

**PrintImage.php**

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/classes/Galerias.php');
$a = new \Galerias();

$i = $_GET['i'];
$w = $_GET['w'];
$h = $_GET['h'];
$q = $_GET['q'];

$a->Pintar($i, $w, $h, $q);

unset($a);
```

**Gallery.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Galerias;
include_once 'Database.php';
include_once 'Utils.php';
use \Database;
use \Utils;

class Galerias {

    private $img_max_width = 1024;
    private $img_max_height = 768;
    private $img_quality = 85;

    function __construct(){
        $this->Database = new Database();
        $this->Utils = new Utils();
    }

    public function Pintar($id, $width, $height, $quality){
        $query = "select (select titulo from imagenes where id=$id) as titulo, (select imagen from imagenes where id=$id) as imagen";
        $data = $this->Database->GetData($query);
        $titulo = $data[0]['titulo'];
        $tmp = $data[0]['imagen'];
        $dataimg = $this->Utils->formatImage("string", $tmp, $width, $height, false);
        $mime = $dataimg[1];
        header("Content-type: $mime");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$titulo");
        imagejpeg($dataimg[0], null, $quality);
    }
}
```

**Database.php**:

```
    <?php
namespace Database;
include_once 'Utils.php';
use \Utils;

class Database {

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "user";
    private $pass = "pass";
    private $daba = "database";
    private $link;
    public $Utils;

    function __construct(){
        $this->Open();
        $this->Utils = new Utils();
    }

    function __destruct(){
        error_log('Database destruct');
    }

    private function Open(){
        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
        error_log('open succeeded');
        mysql_select_db($this->daba, $this->link) or $this->Utils->newEx("Class Database->Open(): ".mysql_error());
    }
    private function Close(){
        mysql_close($this->link) or $this->Utils->newEx("Class Database->Close(): ".mysql_error());
        error_log('close succeeded');
    }

    public function GetData($query){
        $data = array();
        $query = mysql_query($query) or $this->Utils->newEx("Class Database->GetData(): ".mysql_error(), true);
        while( $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
            $data[] = $result;
        }
        $this->FreeResults($query);
        return $data;
    }

    public function InsertData($query){
        if( !mysql_query($query) ){
            $this->Utils->newEx("Class Database->InsertData(): ". mysql_error(), true);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function DeleteData($query){
        if( !mysql_query($query) ){
            $this->Utils->newEx("Class Database->DeleteData(): ". mysql_error(), true);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function FreeResults($res = null){
        if( !is_null($res) ) mysql_free_result($res);
    }
}
```

I am calling database too many times, because I have to load ~50/100 images per gallery.
The question is, how can I do this task efficiently? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sidenote: Typo ? => `include_once(../classes/Gallery.php');` - if not, missing a quote. SO's syntax highlighter never lies ;-)

Comment: Jay, the OP fixed the missing quote lol

Comment: I know lol I think both of you were at the very same time @JayBlanchard

Comment: The only way to do what you want to do here is to modify your gallery class such that it accepts *n* number of possible entries, constructs a single INSERT statement and then executes that statement.

Comment: Well, I am looking for ways to do it, **not the code at all**

Comment: Great! Because it would be hard for us to re-code your gallery class or your database class since we don't have access to their entirety.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well I thought that the code posted is enough to understand it. Anyway, I don't understand what you say... I am calling to database class for each image, because `<img src="print.php" />` makes one call per image. And the class is constructed and destructed each time. How I keep the connection? Is it possible? Can you explain your comment a little more please? If needed, I can edit the post to add the entire code

Comment: 2 negative votes, 0 useful answers. I think people here lose direction. Please, who vote negative, at least leave a comment helping to improve the question or the solution -.-"

Comment: You should STRONGLY consider moving the images into file storage and only store the path to those images in the DB.  This would significantly minimize the bandwidth being used for moving data between app server and DB. You could simply populate this file storage with different images sized on an as-needed basis and also remove the need to generate images on the fly each time.

Comment: @MikeBrant Thank you very much, I guess that is the only way to do it well. The site already had the images in the database and I was looking the way to minimize the job. I created some classes to clarify but that system of image painting is little weird. If you post that as  an answer I will accept it. Is all that I needed

Comment: Well looks that there is more info, I will study it before empty the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the logical system to reduce -considerably- the amount of calls to the database. Before, I used a PHP file as image `src` to print images (with its headers, etc) directly from the database. This is a terrible fail. The problems to solve were:

1. I need to use a PHP file as image src, passing an ID, width, height and quality. And, of course, it has to be a friendly uri. So I can't use base64 encoding to print images. It has to be a PHP file (other file, other process, it isn't connected to the first one).
2. I use a shared hosting, the thinking of loading -nice- extensions like memcache is not viable.
3. Problem 2 tells me that I can't save images (or other data) in any place to use along the site. (It's wrong).

What I did (after thinking and searching and thinking...) is to use `$_SESSION` to store, previous serializing, all images. So, I solved all the problems. Now, have to look for a valid logic to populate the code. The result looks like this:

```
// Session Cache Class (static)

namespace SessionCache;
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');  // this is the best issue of this system
session_start();

class SessionCache {

    // todo: add the possible to expire the session

    private static $SessionName = 'SessionCache';

    public static function Check($name){
        if( empty($_SESSION[self::$SessionName]) ) return false;
        if( empty($_SESSION[self::$SessionName][$name]) ) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public static function Set($name, $data){
        if( self::Check($name) ) return;
        $data = serialize($data);
        $_SESSION[self::$SessionName][$name] = $data;
    }

    public static function Get($name){
        if( self::Check($name) ){
            $data = unserialize($_SESSION[self::$SessionName][$name]);
            return $data;
        }
        else return null;
    }

    public static function Flush($name){
        if( self::Check($name) ) unset($_SESSION[self::$SessionName][$name]);
    }

    public static function Destroy(){
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

Now, the (current) logic:

```
// Images Class. Here I use some extra stuff. Feel free to read the comments 

namespace AdminPanel;
include_once 'SessionCache.php';
include_once 'Database.php';
include_once 'Utils.php';
use \AdminPanel\Database;
use \AdminPanel\Utils;
use SessionCache\SessionCache;
use stdClass;

class Patrocinios {

    private $cache_name = 'Patrocinadores';
    private $img_width = 225;
    private $img_height = 70;
    private $img_quality = 100;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->Database = new \AdminPanel\Database();
        $this->Utils = new \AdminPanel\Utils();
    }
    private function CreateImageCache(){
        if( SessionCache::Check($this->cache_name) ) return null;
        $query = "select * from patrocinadores";
        $this->Database->Open();
        $data = $this->Database->GetData($query);
        $this->Database->Close();
        $patros = new stdClass();
        if( count($data) > 0 ){
            for( $i=0; $i<count($data); $i++ ){
                $id = $data[$i]['id'];
                $nombre = $data[$i]['nombre'];
                $uri = $data[$i]['web'];
                $mimetype = $data[$i]['tipo'];
                $imagedata = $data[$i]['imagen'];
                $patros->patro[$id] = new stdClass();
                $patros->patro[$id]->id = $id;
                $patros->patro[$id]->nombre = $nombre;
                $patros->patro[$id]->uri = $uri;
                $patros->patro[$id]->mimetype = $mimetype;
                $patros->patro[$id]->data = $imagedata;     // the image BLOB
            }
        }
        SessionCache::Set($this->cache_name, $patros);
    }

    public function GetPatrocinadores(){    // this method is the only one called from the main view
        $this->CreateImageCache();
        $patros = SessionCache::Get($this->cache_name);
        return $patros;
    }

    public function Pintar($id, $width, $height, $quality){     // this method is called from the PHP file used to print the images
        if( !SessionCache::Check($this->cache_name) ) $patros = $this->GetPatrocinadores();
        else $patros = SessionCache::Get($this->cache_name);
        $dataimg = $this->Utils->formatImage("string", $patros->patro[$id]->data, $width, $height);     // creates new image with desired measures and quality
        header('Content-Type: '.$patros->patro[$id]->mimetype);
        header('Content-Length: '.strlen($patros->patro[$id]->data));
        imagejpeg($dataimg[0], null, $quality);
    }
}
```

I just have a variable with the name of the session object (`$cache_name`). First I check if exists (from previous call). If not, I populate a `stdClass()` object with the information from the database and store it in the session.

```
<ul id="ulPatrocinadores">
    <?php
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/classes/Patrocinios.php';
    $p = new \AdminPanel\Patrocinios();
    $patros = $p->GetPatrocinadores();
    $str = '';
    foreach( $patros as $value ){
        foreach( $value as $patro ){
            $id = $patro->id;
            $nombre = str_replace(" ", "_", $patro->nombre);
            $web = $patro->uri;
            $str .= '<li>';
            $str .= '<a href="'.$web.'" title="'.$nombre.'" target="_blank"><img src="/'.$nombre.'_pat-i='.$id.'&w=225&h=70&q=85" alt="'.$nombre.'" /></a>';
        }
    }
    echo $str;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Above is the main view which images are printed. Note that anchors and image sources goes to the PHP file that calls to the method `Pintar()`. I use a `RewriteRule` to redirect it.

```
<?php
include_once '../scripts/PrintPartner.php';
$a = new \AdminPanel\Patrocinios();

$i = $_GET['i'];
$w = $_GET['w'];
$h = $_GET['h'];
$q = $_GET['q'];

$a->Pintar($i, $w, $h, $q);

unset($a);
```

And so, I finally achieve it. I don't know if this is a good system because `$_SESSION` is relational to php `memory_limit`, but after two days of thinking about it, I couldn't get something better.

What I achieve:

1. Before: one query for each image to the database. Now: one query for all images for one session (or the time that I could need).
2. Keep of the friendly uris with creating of the image file on the fly as needed, still using a PHP file as image `src`.
3. A good system to reduce calls to the database, also using a shared hosting.

Hope this experience helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Your real question is: How can i minimize the amount of calls to the database.

The data is stored in the database so will have to do a call to retrieve the data. However  what do you need to ask yourself, do i **really** need to ask the question every time?

In your current object model, you retrieve the unique data for every picture only when the object is created. This will add one call every time you want to read the info. This is a very common mistake to do and is something that (as you already realized) doesn't scale at all.

What you need is to make the object already have the data before the call. There is numerous ways to do this. Object Factories, Cached object, memcache, redis the list can be as long as there is active developers out there. 
I'm inviting you to try to think outside the box and find a solution. Because if you understand the problem and solve it you will get a better grasp of object models and the pitfalls.

Lets take it again, are you sure you need to make the database call in the construction of the object? If you know the subset of the data you need, you should ask for in bulk. That will remove a lot of queries to the database.

Perhaps the `Galerias` could have function where you grab a lot of `Pintar` in one go?

I know this isn't a "do this" answer and probably will get down voted. But at least try :).

**Also: Never use the query parameters $_GET $_POST directly without sanitize them first!!**

Comment: I don't want a "do this" answer, I want information. I am able enough to learn all necessary to get targets. So, thank you for your answer. I will study it. I don't forget sanitizations, but thank you for warning :) I will tell you something when I achieve results. Pd: Really I didn't know how to make the question.

Comment: Well... I have all images stored in an object (using `stdClass()` I changed the logic and stored the array from database into an object), but now I can't imagine how to paint them. Does I need to use always an external php file what contains the headers for the image and paint it? If is an external file, each call to any class is new, nothing exists yet, so I don't have nothing. I think using memcache is little wild, Is there some way? -.-" Uh.. More tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Well I wanted to use memcache but I am using a shared server, and this extension is not available. Anyway, I could store all images in an unique object. The problem is that I can't print them. Object factory design is not valid either. I am like at start. Base64 is not a good idea for printing images because I need friendly uris. I think I will keep searching info for a while.

Comment: Ok, I think I looked all. Memcache is a nice idea but I use a shared server. Anyway, I will use `$_SESSION` to store the images. The amount of MB can be established into `ini_set()`. By serializing the images (and other data) into session I could decrease considerably the calls to the database. Currently, I do one call per gallery (like 50-10 images) instead of one call per image. Later I will post how I resolved this as answer, because I got the solution. Thank you again @ztripez, your answer made me think more and better.